# If $u_n$ is bounded and pointwise convergent, then $u_n$ convges in $W_{2,p}$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, elliptic-operators

I'm reading this [paper](http://math.arizona.edu/~dsattinger/MM.pdf) about solving semilinear elliptic pde's through iterated approximations. The line i'm trying to understand is

"Then, since $u_k = Tu_{k-1}$ and since $\{u_k\}$ is a bounded, pointwise convergent sequence, it converges in $W_{2,p}$."

The operator $T$ is defined by defining $Tu$ to be the $v$ such that $(L-\Omega)v = f(x,u)+\Omega u$.

They key information seems to be that assumptions imply $f(x,u_n) + \Omega u_n$ is pointwise convergent, and that the solution operator to $(L-\Omega)v = \phi$ (with boundary conditions $v=0$ on boundary for simplicity) maps $L_p$ continuously into $W_{2,p}$.

Why does the quoted line hold?

Comment: Insufficient information to answer the question. Is $\{u_k\}$ bounded in $W^{2,p}$? What is $f$? Is $f$ the only nonlinear term? What is $\Omega:?\to?$. Describe the domain: bounded-unbounded-smooth-nonsmooth. How do the dimension and $p$ relate to each other?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a bounded smooth domain (the paper says $C^{2,\alpha}$, but this can be weakened). The author **concludes** that $\{u_k\}$ is bounded in $W^{2,p}$ from knowing it is uniformly bounded pointwise. And he claims the statement for all $p \in [1,\infty)$, no relationship to thhe dimension of the space.

Comment: Still not enough information: 1. Is $L$ a linear 2nd order operator? 2. Is $\Omega$ a linear 1st order operator? 3. Is $f(\cdot,u)$ continuos in $u$ from what to what? Maybe this $f$ is a Caratheodory function, or maybe it is a mapping $\mathbb{R}\times W^{2,p}\to L^p$, or anything else?

Comment: $\Omega$ is a constant. Just assume $f$ doesn't depend on $x$, i.e. $f=f(u)$. and $f$ is $C^\infty$ positive increasing convex if it helps. You can read the first four pages of the paper I linked if you want more specifics on the assumptions, but I hope this is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link makes it all clear. The sequence $\{u_k\}$ is uniformly bounded monotone decreasing, and hence poinwise convergent. The operator $T$ is a composition of the nonlinear operation $u\to f(x,u)+\Omega u$ with the inversion of the linear elliptic operator bounded from $L^p$ to $W^{2,p}$. With $\{f(x,u_k)\}$ being bounded uniformly on the range of $\{u_k\}$, the nonlinear operation $u_k\to f(x,u_k)+\Omega u_k$ takes uniformly bounded pointwise convergent $\{u_k\}$ into uniformly bounded pointwise convergent sequence, convergent as well in $L^p$ by the Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem. The inversion of the linear elliptic operator bounded from $L^p$ to $W^{2,p}$ does the rest, taking the sequence convergent in $L^p$ into the sequence convergent in $W^{2,p}$.